# Inserters in C++ confusion

Tags: c++, inserter

So I dont understand how to use inserters in this situation. I know what are inserters, I know about std::front_inserter and std::back_inserter and std::inserter but I am confused about this problem which I will present now.
I need to make function, which will transform elemets of vector and put them in deque(or vector nevermind, its "generic" function anyway).
That function has 5 parameters, which one of them is another function(which can have only one parameter, it is not specified what type(i mean it can be reference,iterator,pointer...... whatever)).

If my vector is:

```
std::vector<int> v={1,2,3,4,5};
```

I need to make some modification, with lambda function, which will make my deque have elements like this:

```
25 16 9 4 1
```

So you see that first element of deque is last element of vector ^2 (you can see what I want to do).
So my question is:
How can the problem be done using inserters? I mean should I somehow put inserter in lambda fucntion? Maybe lambda should be like this:

```
[](int x) { 
x=x*x;
std::front_inserter(q);
}
```

I was thinking about this but then I dont understand how will this lambda work when I send it as parameter of this "big" function? How it will know what is q inside big function?

I hope you understand what I want to do.

Here is example.
So I have to make some function, and this is prototype(lets say it is void):

```
typename<template Type1, template Type2>
void Fun(Type1 p1,Type1 p2,Type2 p3,Type2 p4,void (*f)(std::remove_reference<decltype(*p1)>::type) );
```

Lets say that I have the following code in main:

```
int main() {
std::vector<int> v={1,2,3,4,5};
std::deque<int> d(5);
Fun(v.begin(),v.end(),d.begin(),d.end(), /* some lambda function */);
```

Comment: "*I hope you understand what I want to do.*" No, I don't. What are the 5 parameters of your function for?

Comment: You can see from the call of Fun ...

Comment: Yes, that call makes no sense. Please describe the exact terms of the problem that you're trying to solve with this function.

Comment: I mean instead of creating function, I can use some already existing funciton. That make sense now? And then what function should I use? std::front_inserter ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is impossible to accomplish that with a function that has that type. And with a range given for output, inserters are pointless.

Comment: Output deque can be with no dimension.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build std::transform and you are new to generic programming. To answer your question, the functor's argument must be the same value type as the source container.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the transformation, not in implementing a function with that type,

```
std::deque<int> d;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::front_inserter(d), [](int x){return x * x;});
```

or

```
std::deque<int> d;
std::transform(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), std::back_inserter(d), [](int x){return x * x;});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `std::for_each(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), [&](int x) { d.push_back(x*x); });`?

Comment: @melpomene That depends on what level of the spheres of functional programming you're comfortable in.

Comment: He could, but I point that I want to use inserters ;)
Thanks I think I can use this for solving my problem. So I can normally isntead of d.begin() use std::front_inserter(d) ?

Comment: @pino123 You would use regular iterators for overwriting, inserters for inserting.